# Struts2's convention plugin doesn't scan jars in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: struts2, jar, convention

I packaged some actions in jar files and put these files in WEB-INF/lib.
Also,I've configed struts.convention.action.includeJars constant. But I found convention plugin doesn't scan jars in WEB-INF/lib. See org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.

My Env:
 - tomcat 6.0.5
 - struts2.3.14.3 GA
 - spring 3.0.5

how can convention plugin scan my jars? Are there any method to reuse actions in jar file.

Comment: It scans by giving a constant value that used to mach jar names to regex expression. What jar names or expression did you use?

Comment: <constant name="struts.convention.action.includeJars" value=".*?/webapp.*?jar(!/)?,.*?/webapp*?jar(!/)?" />

Comment: But the problem is the convention plugin doesn't scan web-inf/lib, it only scan tomcat/lib and web-inf/classes.

Comment: Try to add struts.convention.action.fileProtocols=jar,zip

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in convention plugin of struts2.3.14.3 GA.

please see : [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4038).

Get the latest version of PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder, then add these in struts.xml:

```
<bean type="org.apache.struts2.convention.ActionConfigBuilder" name="ActionConfigBuilder_bugfix" class="bugfix.struts2.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder" />
<constant name="struts.convention.actionConfigBuilder" value="ActionConfigBuilder_bugfix" />
```

Comment: And convention plugin doesn'r recognize the jar exported in Eclipse.